# How to fly to an exact location with dragons?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

I have the Dragonborn dlc and the Bend Will shout. When I use it on dragons, they will land for me and I can ride them. But it seems that the only thing I can do with them is attack other creatures. How do I get the dragon to fly to a location without quick travelling? Or is this impossible?

Comment: You fast travel.  "How do I get the dragon to fly to a location *without quick travelling?*" - You don't.  Note that fast travel on a dragon is nearly instantaneous (very little game time passes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Kevin has pointed out in the comments and [the Wiki points out](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Riding#Travel), it's not possible to actually specify a location for the dragon to travel to. In this sense: the dragon is not a mount. You are able to fast travel on the dragon (but you cannot travel between Skyrim and Solstheim) as you would normally.

Answer (score 0):

I fast travel with my newly obtained dragon after using bend-will on him. If I don't feel like battling him alone I go to smaller towns (via fast travel) dismount ( pushing X ). He will then try attacking after a moment but you now have back up.